# What is the meaning of "#" in ":g/pattern/z#.5"

Tags: ex-command

Like the title, What is the meaning of `#` in `:g/pattern/z#.5`.

`:g/pattern/z#.5` and `:g/pattern/z.5`return the same output for me.

In addition, If I want to help description of `#` with `:h` command, how to find it?

`:h #` seems to show another description which is about search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this context `z.5` and `z#.5` are identical.
You find the help under `:help :#`

Comment: They are not identical if `set nonumber`.